# How to create two fields from the same group in hydra-python?

Tags: fb-hydra

My config files structure:

```
config
├── train_dataset
│   ├── adobe5k.yaml
│   ├── my_train_data1.yaml
│   └── cifar10.yaml
├── valid_dataset
│   ├── adobe5k.yaml
│   └── cifar10.yaml
└── config.yaml
```

And my `config.yaml` is:

```
# other configs
...

defaults:
  - train_dataset: adobe5k
  - valid_dataset: adobe5k
```

As you see, I have 2 fields named `valid_dataset` and `train_dataset` in my config, whose value is selected from its own config group. What should I do to make values of the two fields selected from the same group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [a config group more than once](https://hydra.cc/docs/next/advanced/overriding_packages#using-a-config-group-more-than-once). Assume that you moved your dataset configurations into a single `datasets` directory. Then you can re-use them as follows.

```yaml
- defaults:
  - datasets@train_dataset: adobe5k
  - datasets@valid_dataset: adobe5k
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Defaults List interpolation to achieve that. The [Default List](https://hydra.cc/docs/advanced/defaults_list#interpolation-in-the-defaults-list) page high level information and you find a more practical example [here](https://hydra.cc/docs/patterns/specializing_config) for some details.

```yaml
defaults:
  - train_dataset: adobe5k
  - valid_dataset: ${train_dataset}
```

This way, it will be enough for you to override train_dataset and the validation dataset would match it automatically (unless you override it too).

Comment: What to do if I want valid_dataset to be another value from the train_dataset group? More broadly, is it possible to create just a dataset group and assign files interchangeably to train_dataset or valid_dataset?

Comment: Please ask a different question. I don't think I fully understand your question and I am 100% sure I can't answer it in this comment form.

Comment: Asked a new question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68556877/hydra-how-to-assign-config-files-from-same-group-to-two-different-fields