# Hydra : how to assign config files from same group to two different fields

Tags: hydra

Here is my config directory structure,

```
config
|
--scenes
  |
  -- aaa.yaml
  -- bbb.yaml
  -- ccc.yaml
-- myconfig.yaml
```

```
aaa.yaml
--------
field_xxx: "someval"
field_yyy: "someval"
field_zzz: "someval"

bbb.yaml
--------
field_xxx: "someval"
field_yyy: "someval"
field_zzz: "someval"
```

`myconfig.yaml` has two fields `src_scene` and `dst_scene`. Currently I've hardcoded the fields and values for `aaa.yaml` and `bbb.yaml` into `myconfig.yaml` as follows,

```
myconfig.yaml
-------
src_scene:
   field_xxx: "someval"
   field_yyy: "someval"
   field_zzz: "someval"

dst_scene:
   field_xxx: "someval"
   field_yyy: "someval"
   field_zzz: "someval"
```

Ideally, I want to be able to assign these fields values from any of the config files in scenes group. Something like below,

```
src_scene: scenes/aaa.yaml
dst_scene: scenes/bbb.yaml
```

What is the right way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the same config group multiple times, you can use [package override](https://hydra.cc/docs/advanced/overriding_packages).

Read the whole page, but look in particular at the [last section](https://hydra.cc/docs/advanced/overriding_packages#using-a-config-group-more-than-once).